Restrictions of Galois representations
What field embeddings do I need to fix so that if I have a Galois representation $\rho:G_F \to GL(V)$, where $F$ is a number field, then for all finite extensions $L/F$ and places $v$ of F, I can talk about $\rho|_{G_L}$ and $\rho|_{G_{F_v}}$ unambiguously (i.e. not up to conjugation)?
Attempt:
For all perfect field, fix an algebraic closure $\bar F$ of $F$ and write $G_F=Gal(\bar F/F)$. For every number field $F$ and each place $v$ of $F$, fix an embedding $\bar F\to \bar F_v$ extending $F\to F_v$.
Then I have $\rho|_{G_{F_v}}$ for all places $v$ of $F$. However, if $L/F$ is a finite extension, then I'm not sure how to define $\rho|_{G_L}$ (functorially in L).
The problem is elements of $G_L$ acts on $\bar L$ while those of $G_F$ acts on $\bar F$. Of course $\bar L \cong \bar F$, but this isomorphism is not canonical and the data that I fixed don't seem to induce such a map. If I choose them arbitrary, the restriction is not functorial.

There is really no good solution to those issues. You can only define the restriction $\rho|_{G_L}$ absolutely unambiguously if you are given $L$ as a subfield of your chosen closure $\overline{F}$ – not just as an abstract finite extension.

There's a philosophy (which I've heard attributed to Barry Mazur) that $Gal(\overline{F} / F)$ shouldn't be thought of as an actual group which has actual elements, but as a "group up to conjugation"; i.e. a statement about it which isn't conjugation-invariant is of no interest.
